# How is OpenPose implementing its loss function with the shape of output and groudtruth mismatch?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, loss-function, openpose

I have recently been implementing a model based on OpenPose. In OpenPose, it uses VGG as its backbone model to extract feature maps, but VGG contains max pooling layers and that will reduce the shape of the output to 1/4. Here is the model structure of OpenPose:

```
VGGOpenPose(
  (model0): OpenPose_Feature(
    (model): Sequential(
      (0): Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
      (1): ReLU(inplace=True)
      (2): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
      (3): ReLU(inplace=True)
      (4): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
      (5): Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
      (6): ReLU(inplace=True)
      (7): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
      (8): ReLU(inplace=True)
      (9): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
      (10): Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
      (11): ReLU(inplace=True)
      (12): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
      (13): ReLU(inplace=True)
      (14): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
      (15): ReLU(inplace=True)
      (16): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
      (17): ReLU(inplace=True)
      (18): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
      (19): Conv2d(256, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
      (20): ReLU(inplace=True)
      (21): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
      (22): ReLU(inplace=True)
      (23): Conv2d(512, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
      (24): ReLU(inplace=True)
      (25): Conv2d(256, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
      (26): ReLU(inplace=True)
    )
  )
  (model1_1): Sequential(
    (0): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (1): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (2): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (3): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (4): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (5): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (6): Conv2d(128, 512, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
    (7): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (8): Conv2d(512, 38, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
  )
  (model2_1): Sequential(
    (0): Conv2d(185, 128, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(1, 1), padding=(3, 3))
    (1): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (2): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(1, 1), padding=(3, 3))
    (3): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (4): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(1, 1), padding=(3, 3))
    (5): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (6): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(1, 1), padding=(3, 3))
    (7): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (8): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(1, 1), padding=(3, 3))
    (9): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (10): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
    (11): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (12): Conv2d(128, 38, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
  )
  (model3_1): Sequential(
    (0): Conv2d(185, 128, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(1, 1), padding=(3, 3))
    (1): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (2): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(1, 1), padding=(3, 3))
    (3): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (4): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(1, 1), padding=(3, 3))
    (5): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (6): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(1, 1), padding=(3, 3))
    (7): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (8): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(1, 1), padding=(3, 3))
    (9): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (10): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
    (11): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (12): Conv2d(128, 38, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
  )
  (model4_1): Sequential(
    (0): Conv2d(185, 128, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(1, 1), padding=(3, 3))
    (1): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (2): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(1, 1), padding=(3, 3))
    (3): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (4): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(1, 1), padding=(3, 3))
    (5): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (6): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(1, 1), padding=(3, 3))
    (7): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (8): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(1, 1), padding=(3, 3))
    (9): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (10): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
    (11): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (12): Conv2d(128, 38, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
  )
  (model5_1): Sequential(
    (0): Conv2d(185, 128, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(1, 1), padding=(3, 3))
    (1): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (2): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(1, 1), padding=(3, 3))
    (3): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (4): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(1, 1), padding=(3, 3))
    (5): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (6): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(1, 1), padding=(3, 3))
    (7): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (8): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(1, 1), padding=(3, 3))
    (9): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (10): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
    (11): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (12): Conv2d(128, 38, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
  )
  (model6_1): Sequential(
    (0): Conv2d(185, 128, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(1, 1), padding=(3, 3))
    (1): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (2): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(1, 1), padding=(3, 3))
    (3): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (4): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(1, 1), padding=(3, 3))
    (5): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (6): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(1, 1), padding=(3, 3))
    (7): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (8): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(1, 1), padding=(3, 3))
    (9): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (10): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
    (11): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (12): Conv2d(128, 38, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
  )
  (model1_2): Sequential(
    (0): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (1): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (2): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (3): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (4): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
    (5): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (6): Conv2d(128, 512, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
    (7): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (8): Conv2d(512, 19, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
  )
  (model2_2): Sequential(
    (0): Conv2d(185, 128, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(1, 1), padding=(3, 3))
    (1): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (2): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(1, 1), padding=(3, 3))
    (3): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (4): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(1, 1), padding=(3, 3))
    (5): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (6): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(1, 1), padding=(3, 3))
    (7): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (8): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(1, 1), padding=(3, 3))
    (9): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (10): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
    (11): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (12): Conv2d(128, 19, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
  )
  (model3_2): Sequential(
    (0): Conv2d(185, 128, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(1, 1), padding=(3, 3))
    (1): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (2): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(1, 1), padding=(3, 3))
    (3): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (4): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(1, 1), padding=(3, 3))
    (5): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (6): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(1, 1), padding=(3, 3))
    (7): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (8): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(1, 1), padding=(3, 3))
    (9): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (10): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
    (11): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (12): Conv2d(128, 19, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
  )
  (model4_2): Sequential(
    (0): Conv2d(185, 128, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(1, 1), padding=(3, 3))
    (1): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (2): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(1, 1), padding=(3, 3))
    (3): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (4): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(1, 1), padding=(3, 3))
    (5): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (6): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(1, 1), padding=(3, 3))
    (7): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (8): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(1, 1), padding=(3, 3))
    (9): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (10): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
    (11): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (12): Conv2d(128, 19, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
  )
  (model5_2): Sequential(
    (0): Conv2d(185, 128, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(1, 1), padding=(3, 3))
    (1): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (2): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(1, 1), padding=(3, 3))
    (3): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (4): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(1, 1), padding=(3, 3))
    (5): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (6): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(1, 1), padding=(3, 3))
    (7): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (8): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(1, 1), padding=(3, 3))
    (9): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (10): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
    (11): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (12): Conv2d(128, 19, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
  )
  (model6_2): Sequential(
    (0): Conv2d(185, 128, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(1, 1), padding=(3, 3))
    (1): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (2): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(1, 1), padding=(3, 3))
    (3): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (4): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(1, 1), padding=(3, 3))
    (5): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (6): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(1, 1), padding=(3, 3))
    (7): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (8): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(1, 1), padding=(3, 3))
    (9): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (10): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
    (11): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (12): Conv2d(128, 19, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
  )
)
```

In the origin paper, it says the groundtruth heatmap and paf is of the same width and height as the input image.
[OpenPose: Realtime Multi-Person 2D Pose Estimation using Part Afﬁnity Fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mzpT.png)

And I have searched for a few implementations of OpenPose in Python. Most of them use element-wise loss function to calculate the loss between the output and groundtruth label, just the same as the function mentioned in the Paper:

[loss function in openpose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsKOu.png)

I was wondering whether the output of OpenPose is of different size as the input image and if it is how is OpenPose calculating the loss function between the output and the groundtruth heatmap/paf?

Comment: Did you get any thing about it? I'm also searching for this thing.

Comment: @Erric Yeah, most of the implementations of openpose reduce the size of the output feature maps to 1/4 or 1/8 of the original input size. This may be helpful to keep more salient features and reduce memory usage. When calculating the loss function, they use the resized version of pafs/heatmaps, which is generated before according to the rescale factor. In testing phase, they use interpolation methods to upscale the output keypoint coordinates to the original scale.